Is there a way to refer to elements of a vector input in a conditional panel in R shiny
I want to refer to a specific element of a vector input in a conditional panel. For instance, suppose the user gets a checkbox group input with two fruit options- Apple and Banana. If the user selects only Apple and not Banana, a conditional panel is created that further prompts the user to select the color of the Apple (Red or green). If the user instead selects only Banana, a separate conditional panel is created that asks for the color of the Banana (green or yellow). I tried doing this with input.fruit.includes() as a condition, but this fails. Is there any other way to do this in R shiny? More generally, how do I put in a condition that asks for a specific element to be contained in a vector. Thanks!
Included is my code. I would appreciate any help with fixing it.
information <- c("Apple", "Banana")
applecolor <- c("Red", "Green")
bananacolor <- c("Yellow", "Green")
ui <- fluidPage(checkboxGroupInput("fruit", "Select your fruit of choice", information),
                conditionalPanel(condition = "input.fruit.includes('Apple
                                 ') && !input.fruit.includes('Banana')",
                                 selectInput("color1", "Enter the apple's color", applecolor)
                                 ),
                conditionalPanel(condition = "input.fruit.includes('Banana') && !input.fruit.includes('Apple')",
                                 selectInput("color2", "Enter the banana's color", bananacolor)),
textOutput("result"))
server <- function(input, output, session){y <- reactive(input$info)
output$result <- renderPrint({"Good choice!"})}
shinyApp(ui, server)


I think you will find the %in% operator useful here for detecting the presence of each, then checking for the length of the input vector for further matching.

@mhovd I did try using $in% and %nin% to check the presence and absence of specific values. However, the output displays both conditional panels irrespectively. Can you tell me the syntax for checking the input length and how I would use that here? Thanks!

It seems that you only have one bug in your code and this is the newline in input.fruit.includes('Apple                                  ') which leads to an error when parsing the expression. Replacing it with input.fruit.includes('Apple') yields a working code for me.

just want to point out that you can avoid needing to write javascript syntax by using other shiny methods, in this case uiOutput/renderUI
library(shiny)
information <- c("Apple", "Banana")
applecolor <- c("Red", "Green")
bananacolor <- c("Yellow", "Green")
ui <- fluidPage(checkboxGroupInput("fruit", "Select your fruit of choice", information),
                uiOutput("b1"),
                uiOutput("b2"),
                textOutput("result"))
server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$b1 <- renderUI({
    fr <- req(input$fruit)
    if(('Apple' %in% fr) && (! 'Banana' %in% fr))
    selectInput("color1", "Enter the apple's color", applecolor)
  })
  
  output$b2 <- renderUI({
    fr <- req(input$fruit)
    if(('Banana' %in% fr) && (! 'Apple' %in% fr))
    selectInput("color1", "Enter the banana's color", bananacolor)
  })
  y <- reactive(input$info)
output$result <- renderPrint({"Good choice!"})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)

